# docker builds failing with "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to setup docker on my windows11 machine and building sample application.

```
$ docker build -t getting-started .
```

if fails with

```
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN yarn install --production                                                                             8.1s
------
 > [4/4] RUN yarn install --production:
0.413 yarn install v1.22.19
0.470 [1/4] Resolving packages...
0.626 [2/4] Fetching packages...
1.063 error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/array-flatten/-/array-flatten-1.1.1.tgz: unable to get local issuer certificate".
1.063 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/app/yarn-error.log".
1.063 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
4.873 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     WORKDIR /app
   5 |     COPY . .
   6 | >>> RUN yarn install --production
   7 |     CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
   8 |     EXPOSE 3000
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I tried couple of applications, failing with same kind of error. Is it related to Git?

Comment: Please add your `Dockerfile` to the question.

Comment: It's certainly not git. It might be (the contents of) your base image or any changes you have made so far. It might be your host -- Windows machines in particular often have some kind of security software installed doing TLS interception, which would cause this. It might be the network you are using. If your image has openssl, you could run in it `openssl s_client -connect registry.yarnpkg.com:443 -showcerts` (if openssl below 1.1.1 add `-servername registry.yarnpkg.com`) to see whether you are actually getting good certs or not.